# Why does this registration cause StructureMap to throw Error 104

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

I would like to be able to resolve an enumerable collection of `IRepository<T> where T : IDocument`

In my registry class I've added the following registration code:

```
this.For<IRepository<IDocument>>().Add<Repository<Document>>();
this.For<IRepository<IDocument>>().Add<Repository<AnotherDocumentType>>();
```

Both the classes `Document` and `AnotherDocumentType` implement the interface `IDocument`, and `Repository<T>` implements `IRepository<T>`.  I'm new to structure map, and I don't really understand the error message.  All classes involved have default constructors.

> Structuremap is throwing the following error Test
>   Name: can_resolve_a_collection_of_document_repositories Test
>   FullName: my.test.IoCTest.can_resolve_a_collection_of_document_repositories
>   Test
>   Source:   d:\Projects\level\my\mtrunk\src\my.test\IoCTest.cs
>   : line 46 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.138309
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>   my.test.IoCTest.can_resolve_a_collection_of_document_repositories
>   threw exception: 
>   StructureMap.Exceptions.StructureMapConfigurationException:
>   StructureMap configuration failures: Error:  104 Source:  Registry: 
>   StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry, StructureMap,
>   Version=2.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223 Type
>   Instance '613169b9-b8d9-4c80-868a-d6aa47e3d95c' (Configured Instance
>   of my.data.Impl.Repositories.Repository`1[[my.domain.Document,
>   my.domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   my.data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null) cannot
>   be plugged into type my.data.IRepository`1[[my.domain.IDocument,
>   my.domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   my.data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Error:  104 Source:  Registry: 
>   StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry, StructureMap,
>   Version=2.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e60ad81abae3c223 Type
>   Instance '2196350f-0c64-4bd2-92af-9946f1e11862' (Configured Instance
>   of my.data.Impl.Repositories.Repository`1[[my.domain.AnotherDocumentType,
>   my.domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   my.data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null) cannot
>   be plugged into type my.data.IRepository`1[[my.domain.IDocument,
>   my.domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   my.data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Result StackTrace:     at
>   StructureMap.Diagnostics.GraphLog.AssertFailures() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Diagnostics\GraphLog.cs:line
>   68    at StructureMap.Container.construct(PluginGraph pluginGraph) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line
>   576    at StructureMap.Container..ctor(PluginGraph pluginGraph) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line
>   55    at StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(Action`1 action) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\ObjectFactory.cs:line
>   65    at
>   my.test.IoCTest.can_resolve_a_collection_of_document_repositories() in
>   d:\Projects\level\my\mtrunk\src\my.test\IoCTest.cs:line
>   51

Comment: I haven't used StructureMap, but I would guess that this doesn't work, because you are trying to register two implementations for the same interface. How should the container know, which to return when you want to resolve `IRepository<IDocument>`?

Comment: Nope, most containers will allow this.  StructureMap specifically has an `Add` method that is used when you want to resolve a collection of instances (as I do)

Comment: I use this.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>)); to map all Repository implementations in one shot. Maybe this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't StructureMap but the way you're using generics. 
Does `IRepository<IDocument> foo = new Repository<Document>();` build?
Make IRepository covariant (i.e.  `public interface IRepository<out T> where T : IDocument`, the `out` part is important) and try again.

Comment: Yep, thats it.  Too bad I can't change the signature of the IRepository interface.

Comment: Would wrapping the repo help?

`public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetFoo();
}

public interface IMyRepository<out T>
{
    T GetFoo();
}

public class MyRepository<T> : IMyRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repo;

    public MyRepository(IRepository<T> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public T GetFoo()
    {
        return _repo.GetFoo();
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error code.

I made the dumb mistake of not adding the Interface to the Class.

BEFORE

```
public class MyClass //No Interface
```

AFTER

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
```

"That's like so me dude!"